# Gratis 2D floorplan drawing software

Tags: gratis, vector-graphics

I am looking for something like [FlDraw](http://www.fldraw.com/), to allow me to draw floor plans or shopping malls, offices, industrial plants and the like.

[image]

The catch is that I want the parts of the floorplan to be identifiable. That is, I will embed the floorplan in a webpage and when, the user clicks, I want to be able to identify the store, office, room, etc where they clicked, preferably using AngularJs, but plain old JS will do in a pinch.

In fact, this *_might_* be a two part question – one to draw the floor plans, and - the trickier part - a program to split the image into segments (imagine taking a map of the USA and delineating the states) in such a way that (Angular) JS can determine when one is clicked.

I prefer a Windows app, but am also open to Linux.

---

[Update] I require  SVG, with each room delineated by a separate SVG path

---

[Update++] I only want 2D, not 3D, and I only want to draw walls, doors, stairs & the like. What I do not want are lots of options for sofas, filling cabinets, potted plants & the like. This is for shopping malls & industrial plants. I suppose I don’t object of there are some icons toilets, emergency exists, but I can live without those if I have to.

Black & white is just fine. I can add colo(u)r later, in the HTML, if I want it.

The most important thing is that each room is a separate SVG path, so two adjoin rooms really need to two touching but separate” walls” between them, not just a single line. This is so that I can enclosed each room in an SVG path and detect clicks within the room.

Bad ascii art follows

```
+--------------------++--------------------+
|                    ||                    |
|      Room 1        ||      Room 2        |     <----- like this
|                    ||                    |
|   /                ||  /                 |
+--/     ------------++-/        ----------+


+--------------------+--------------------+
|                    |                    |
|      Room 1        |      Room 2        |    <----- NOT like this
|                    |                    |
|   /                |  /                 |
+--/     ------------+-/        ----------+
```

Comment: Consider an [image map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map)

Comment: Excellent idea. I actually coded some stuff using one once & had totally forgotten about it (+1). Now, all need is a floorplan -> image map app :-)

Comment: Or, I might go with the more modern HTML5 canvas, and define each room as a [path](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-paths/) and use `isPointInPath()` to detect clicks

Answer (score 3):

To answer your two questions:

1. I recently had to draw a floor plan and used SweetHome3D to do so (http://www.sweethome3d.com; Windows, Mac OS X 10.4 to 10.12, Linux and Solaris; "Sweet Home 3D is a free interior design application that helps you draw the plan of your house, arrange furniture on it and visit the results in 3D"). I found it very easy to use and it offers different ways to export your plan (PDF, SVG).
2. After drawing your floor plan you could export it as a SVG, split it into different images and scale them as needed by using a vector graphics editor (Illustrator, Inkscape, ..). After that, you could put all the images back together by using HTML/CSS/JS/AngularJS and hook them to one AngularJS function which then handles the onClick.

Comment: Welcom aboard! Good answer :-(  I was afraid that I might have to do that (+1). Do you know of any way to automate the splititng  of the  SVG image?

Comment: Thank you! :) No, I don't know a totally automated way todo so. I normally use Adobe Illustrator for that kind of work. Illustrator offers the possibility to drag&drop different parts of an SVG onto an export field where one then can define how to one-click-export all of the dropped parts (PNG, JPG, SVG, PDF). SweetHome3D creates an SVG with multiple groups of elements. Floors are separate which could be dragged&dropped directly. Walls are connected so you would have to split them manually.

Comment: I am thinking of using Inkscape and putting each room on a separate layer. Viewed with layers overlapping, the floor plan will seem complete, with each room’s walls touching the next room, but I could still export each layer as an HTML5 canvas path.